# tkinter TclError: unknown option on widget attributes

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tcl

This is my first application on Tkinter, I am trying to take inputs from a selected file button from the dropdown menu and trigger the function which is to be executed when the submit button is clicked. This objective is achieved but designing the buttons and labels as required is failing.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1200x800')
root.title("Update System")

label_0 = Label(root, text="Update System",width=25,font=("bold", 25),height=2,bg='brown',fg='white')
label_0.place(x=170,y=30)

root.mainloop()
```

I receive the error `TclError: unknown option "-fg" (for bg-background, height attributes of buttons and labels).` Complete traceback is shown below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-2c166bb79a75> in <module>
      3 root.title("Update System")
      4 
----> 5 label_0 = Label(root, text="Update System",width=25,font=("bold", 25),height=2,bg='brown',fg='white')
      6 label_0.place(x=170,y=30)
      7 

~\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\ttk.py in __init__(self, master, **kw)
    759             relief, text, wraplength
    760         """
--> 761         Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::label", kw)
    762 
    763 

~\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\ttk.py in __init__(self, master, widgetname, kw)
    557             # Load tile now, if needed
    558             _load_tile(master)
--> 559         tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
    560 
    561 

~\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in __init__(self, master, widgetName, cnf, kw, extra)
   2297             del cnf[k]
   2298         self.tk.call(
-> 2299             (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
   2300         for k, v in classes:
   2301             k.configure(self, v)

TclError: unknown option "-height"
```

It would be great if someone can help me understand and figure out this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your code have `from tkinter.ttk import *`? If yes, then you are using `ttk.Label` which does not support `height`, `fg` and `bg` options.  Try changing `Label` to `tk.Label`.

Comment: yes, my code has ttk, I have corrected that and works now. thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are *two* `Label` widgets in Tk and hence in tkinter. The older standard Tk label supports directly setting things like foreground and background colors, whereas the newer Ttk (“Themed Tk”) does not (but instead supports theming, *specifically* it supports following the OS native theme very closely). They're both kept because the new one is definitely not a drop-in replacement for the old, and some applications (maybe yours included) need the exact functionality of the old.

If we look in your traceback, we see this:

> ```
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\ttk.py in __init__(self, master, **kw)
>     759             relief, text, wraplength
>     760         """
> --> 761         Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::label", kw)
>     762 
>     763
> ```

See the `ttk` in there (twice!)? That indicates that you're using the Ttk Label. To fix your immediate problem, *explicitly* use the old one.

```
# Note: tk.Label and not just Label or ttk.Label
label_0 = tk.Label(root, text="Update System", 
                   width=25, font=("bold", 25), height=2, bg='brown', fg='white')
```

The other alternative would be to create a new style that you could apply to just that widget to make it stand out the way you want… but that's a lot more work for a simple one-off label.